# How to find a specific string chunk using regularExpression in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to find a specific chunk of a string using regular expression. I have already a name in this string like aside-canvas. So, When I check for `aside` it returns true `string.match(/aside/)` But it should return false. Because it has `aside-canvas` not just `aside`.

How can I do that with regular expression dynamically.

```js
let 
    string = 'aside-canvas othersName';
//checking for only aside not aside-canvas, so it should return false
```

Comment: How would you check if the class name did *not* have a hyphen?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName('aside-canvas')`? Or `document.querySelector('.aside-canvas')`

Comment: Or if you already have the element: `element.classList.contains('aside-canvas')`

Comment: @Pointy string.match(/singleClassName/);

Comment: checking for a substring in a string

Comment: @Pointy I know that you knew it, Please help

Comment: @MdAlex, I've updated my answer with a regex that will work (as well as a more apt string answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to match an exact string, you don't even need a regex for that:

```js
let string = 'aside-canvas other others';

console.log(string.includes('aside-canvas'))
```

If you want to make sure that different class names in the list are treated separately:

```js
let string = 'aside-canvas other others';

console.log(string.split(' ').includes('aside'))

let string2 = 'aside-canvas other others aside';

console.log(string2.split(' ').includes('aside'))
```

Or if you are really married to the regex idea:

`(?:^| )aside(?:$| )` will check if it's either the start or has a space (to keep boundaries between classes consistent). Then the class name of interest `aside`. Then if it's the end of the string or a space to make sure that's the end of the class name.

```js
let string = 'aside-canvas other others';
let regex = /(?:^| )aside(?:$| )/
console.log(regex.test(string))

let string2 = 'aside-canvas other others aside';

console.log(regex.test(string2))
let word = 'anotherClassName';

let dynamicRegex = new RegExp(`(?:^| )${word}(?:^| )`);
console.log(dynamicRegex);
```

If you want to make the regex dynamically, just create a new instance of RegExp:

Just note that whatever is in word will be treated as regex rather than text. So if you want to match * for instance, you need to escape it out.

```
let word = 'anotherClassName';
let dynamicRegex = new RegExp(`(?:^| )${word}(?:^| )`);
```

Comment: are you aware of the existence of regex word boundaries?

Comment: @PeterSeliger, yes, but `-` also counts as a word boundary, so I had to avoid using them.

Comment: I want to make it dynamically. I mean the ```aside``` class could be anything else then how can I check it ```let word = 'anotherClassName';```

Comment: Can you please suggest me any good source to learn regular expression?

Comment: Where I learned it from was the textbook: `Mastering Regular Expressions`, but [Reference - What does this regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) is a good resource with links to some tutorials gathered by users here.

Comment: @ZacharyHaber Do you know Jeffrey Friedl?